# Mono Monodevelop and SQLite

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to learn how to use SQLite with c# (mono/monodevelop). 
I've included the SQLite reference in my Solution, and I'm trying to compile this simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SqliteTest
{


class SqliteTest 
{
    static void dbstuff ()
    {
        //Creating DB
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
        //Creating a Connection 
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        //Conntecting
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        //Run some sql commands
        string sql = "CREATE TABLE highscores (name VARCHAR(20), score INT)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //This command just indicae the number of rows that have been modified

    }

    static void Main() 
    {
        dbstuff();
    }
}
}
```

But I get this error:

```
The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced
```

How can I solve this ?

I'm a newbie with C#, I hope that somebody can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
using System.Data.Common;
```

in front of the file.

Comment: I've already tried that but without luck. It says that doesn't exist "Common" in Syste.Data

Comment: Are there references for SQLite in project?

Comment: Yes, System.Data.SQLite.dll and  SQLite.Designer.dll

Comment: Okay I've solved it :D I noticed that I was missing System.Data in the referece three, I've added it and then I've copied SQLite.Interop.dll in the build dir! Now it works ! Many thanks ;)